# MS Access Append Query - Field not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an append query which has an Excel Sheet as a datasource. Today the underlying data of one of the fields was changed from `String` to `Long`. In my query table I had this particular field calculated as:

`MSCI: Left([bp_msci_ic_key];2)`

in order to compensate for the change in underlying data format I changed it to...

`MSCI: Left(*Str*([bp_msci_ic_key]);2)`

Unfortunately, the query produces #ERROR with this... *why does this approach not work?*

Here the syntax of the entire SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Position( 
    MoPo_ID, 
    AssetClass_Sub_ID, 
    VALOR, 
    ISIN, 
    [Currency], 
    Position_Name, 
    Weight, 
    Rating, 
    Asset_Country, 
    Issuer_Country, 
    Position_Duration, 
    Position_YieldToMaturity, 
    MSCI_Code, 
    PosValue)
SELECT 
    qry_Position_Load_step1.MoPo_BM_ID, 
    qry_Position_Load_step1.AssetClass_Sub_ID, 
    qry_Position_Load_step1.VALOR, 
    qry_Position_Load_step1.ISIN, 
    IIf([qry_Position_load_step1]![ccy] Is Null And Left([qry_Position_load_step1]![classsub],2)="M_", Mid([qry_Position_load_step1]![classsub],3,Len([qry_Position_load_step1]![classsub])-1),[qry_Position_load_step1]![CCY]) AS CCY,
    qry_Position_Load_step1.NAME_SHORT, 
    qry_Position_Load_step1.Val, 
    tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir, 
    tbl_MopoRohdaten.ass_domi_country, 
    tbl_MopoRohdaten.iss_domi_country, 
    tbl_MopoRohdaten.pos_dur_mod, 
    tbl_MopoRohdaten.pos_ytm, 
    Left(Str([bp_msci_ic_key]),2) AS MSCI, 
    tbl_MopoRohdaten.pos_eop_value
FROM 
    qry_Position_Load_step1 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_MopoRohdaten ON 
            (qry_Position_Load_step1.MoPo_Name_Avaloq = tbl_MopoRohdaten.portf_name) AND 
            (qry_Position_Load_step1.ISIN = tbl_MopoRohdaten.asset_isin);
```

EDIT: A reduced Selection as per comments:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_MopoRohdaten.[bp_msci_ic_key] AS MSCI
FROM 
    qry_Position_Load_step1 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_MopoRohdaten ON 
            (qry_Position_Load_step1.MoPo_Name_Avaloq = tbl_MopoRohdaten.portf_name) AND 
            (qry_Position_Load_step1.ISIN = tbl_MopoRohdaten.asset_isin)
WHERE 
    (((tbl_MopoRohdaten.[bp_msci_ic_key]) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `CStr()`?

Comment: `CStr`is still giving me #Error

Comment: Put in a edit for easier readability.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Thanks. I have yet to figure out how to properly format SQL on here.

Comment: @rohrl77 A good tip when posting large parts of code is to use the `{}` button (or insert 4 spaces in beginning of each row) instead of using single quotation-ish mark (Don't know what to call them). The `{}` gives you a code block with, syntax highlighting and scroll etc. The other way of doing it only gives you a gray text box around it, and is better off used in comments or to highlight some code in plain text.

Comment: @rohrl77 Regarding your problem however, are you trying to add data to the table where MSCI is defined as long, or are you trying to grab the data from it and put into another table?

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Thanks for the explanation on formatting. Will keep this in mind for the future. I am putting the data into a third table that I previously empty.

Comment: @rohrl77 What happens if you run the query as a select? And even more isolate it to only selecting the MSCI-computed column. Then you could also isolate it even further by only selecting `Str([bp_msci_ic_key])`, down until you find where it goes wrong.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl By getting rid of the JOIN the field works as expected with the formula `MSCI: Left(Trim(Str([bp_msci_ic_key]));2)`, however as soon as I use this in combination with the JOIN it stops functioning.

Comment: @rohrl77 If you do a `SELECT` on it WITH the `JOIN`, but removing the `LEFT` and `Str` and such, and only putting out the MSCI field as the raw column data. Does it give you any pointers unto what might be causing the problems?

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Tried your suggestion. I got no results (I double check with Is `Not Null`). Somehow the join is screwing up the result. Will update my OP with this query so you see

Comment: @rohrl77 Wait what? Is your `LEFT JOIN` causing ALL your results to be `NULL`, or did I misunderstand you? Because that would be seriously weird...

Comment: @LudvigRydahl The results are not null, but they show nothing, eventhough I know that there are records that have data (some do not). The underlying table `tblMopoRohdaten` is a linked Excel table btw

Comment: @rohrl77 You should put the condition in the `WHERE`-clause in the `ON`-clause for the joined table instead of the `WHERE`. Putting conditions in the `WHERE` for tables that have been `LEFT JOIN`'d will cause it to have the same effect as a regular `JOIN`.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Ok. But that doesn't yet solve the main problem. My editing buttons have disappaered on my crappy IE browser btw, which is why i have not properly formatted the new SQL according to your suggestion earlier.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl I found the issue. I'll post the answer in a second. The problem had to do with the underlying data. Thank you for all the time you invested! I appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because the underlying data had a broked/incomplete record source. For reasons I am not certain of yet, only a fraction of the underlying data in `tbl_MopoRohdaten` got loaded. Since the query used a double join in matching up the data, it kept on showing a number of records that matched one of the joins.

However, the results that were returned never contained any data for the MSCI field I was having problems with. So naturally, when I used `CStr()` it returned an error, because the field was `Null`.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! :) You can go ahead and accept your own answer, so the question gets marked as resolved :) Happy querying! ;)

Comment: Thanks. I need to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer. :- )